# GUI doesn't show the command at the frame

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I programmed a little game in Java for school. We have library with given functions. I write a code that repeats a command (while), i checked with the println that the command is running correctly, but in the GUI you can't see the result, only the last result.

Project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Ehxz_FAn6BMjVPOWY5MkgycVk&authuser=0

Code:

```
public void spielen () {
        if (guthaben > 0) {
            if (endlosspielAktiv) {
                while (guthaben > 0) {
                    kasten.Ringe.faerbeUm(); //Here the GUI doesn't show the results
                    ZEICHENFENSTER.gibFenster().warte(500);
                    guthabenRunter();
                }
                setEndlosspielAktiv(false);
            } else {
                kasten.Ringe.faerbeUm();
            }
        } else if (guthaben == 0) {
            setEndlosspielAktiv(false);
        }
        guthabenRunter();
    }
```

Comment: We can't help you right now - you need to provide more code to us. Can you try to provide a complete example (that compiles; and that can be run to reproduce your problem)?

Comment: One good thing to do is to write your code in english, so it will be more understandable so the different persons that wants to read your code

Comment: ok is a zip from google drive ok?

Comment: @school_guy Just to be precise: it is totally OK to program your homework using German; but if you intend to ask more questions at stackoverflow, English would work much better.

Comment: i know that, i am trying to programm at home in english, but in school my teacher says i have to use german

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GUI is updated only after all your pending and running methods of the calling thread returned.
In your case the update of the GUI delays until the method `spielen()` returned.

To have an immediate result, you could use an additional Thread like this:

```
public void spielen () {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (guthaben > 0) {
                    if (endlosspielAktiv) {
                        while (guthaben > 0) {
                            kasten.Ringe.faerbeUm();
                            ZEICHENFENSTER.gibFenster().warte(500);                            
                            guthabenRunter();
                        }
                        setEndlosspielAktiv(false);
                    } else {
                        kasten.Ringe.faerbeUm();
                    }
                } else if (guthaben == 0) {
                    setEndlosspielAktiv(false);
                }
                guthabenRunter();
            }
        }).start();        
    }
```

All code of `spielen()` is running asynchronous and doesn't block the method returning.

If you want to know more about threading, i can recommend you reading the according chapter of the (german) E-Book http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel9/javainsel_14_003.htm

Comment: ok, thx i have the one with schrödinger, but havn't been so far in the book, i will search after this chapter, thx for helping